# Association named was not found Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have looked all over the internet but for some reason those answers are close but they don't help me.

So i have a players table and a teams table. A player can belong to multiple teams. A Team can have many players.

So here are my models:
**Liveplayer**:

```
class LivePlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :teamplayers
has_many :fteams, :through => :teamplayers
end
```

**Fteam**:

```
class Fteam < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :liveplayer
end
```

**Teamplayer**:

```
class Teamplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :live_player
belongs_to :fteam
end
```

The names of the tables respectively are live_players and fteams

Here is the html:

```
<select id = "test4" style= float:left>
<% Teamplayer.includes(:live_player).all do |tp| %>
    <option> <%=tp.id %></option>  <- This returns nothing right now
<% end %>
</select>
```

Here is the error:
Association named 'LivePlayer' was not found on Teamplayer; perhaps you misspelled it?

So my question is that which is the problem.

1. The Relations in the models?
2. Should the relations have the table names instead of the model names i.e.: live_players instead of liveplayer?
3. Or is it the way i am using the html to get the values from what i want?

In the end i want to get a list of players on a specific team, i.e. All players on team 1

I also have another table that would associate the 2 tables to each other by the id's of each table that would be stored in the third table. But first i need to figure out what the error means.

**UPDATE**
I don't get the association error any more, but nothing displays, in the selection box in the html, I have updated my models above and html above

Comment: code for the `Teamplayer` class?

Comment: `class Teamplayer < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :fteam
 belongs_to :live_players
end`

Comment: Also this line will not run in the console: `Teamplayer.includes(:live_player).all` It gives the association error : Association live_player was not found in Teamplayer. See model updates

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Teamplayer.includes(:live_players).all do |tp| %>
    <option> <%=tp.teamid %></option>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok some progress, now i get this: uninitialized constant Teamplayer::LivePlayers

Comment: well! in which line ?

Comment: This line: <% Teamplayer.includes(:live_players).all do |tp| %>

Comment: can someone tell me why the following line gives the association error: Teamplayer.includes(:live_player).  Association named 'live_player' was not found on Teamplayer; perhaps you misspelled it? See models above as they are updated

Answer (score 0):

belongs_to are usually singular, especially since your model is singular.  Use dashes if the class is camel-cased.

```
belongs_to :live_player
```

Also - it looks like TeamPlayer is a join table, the other classes should has associations to it.  E.g.

```
class LivePlayer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :team_players
  has_many :fteams, :through => :team_players
end
```

Is there an team_player_id on fteam?  If so, that's the belongs to - maybe the captain or team creator?  If so, you'll have something like this:

```
class Fteam < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :live_player
   has_many :team_players
   has_many :live_players, :through => :team_players
end
```

In the form, to get team ids, you might want to use fteam instead of team_player - it won't have duplicates.

```
<% Fteam.all do |t| %>
    <option> <%= t.id %></option>
<% end %>
```

Comment: so the belongs_to :live_player is what should go in the Teamplayer? And yes teamplayer is a join table with 2 fields playerid and teamid. Fteam does not have a teamplayer id. For the form, if i want to load a team into a list then i can use the fteam id to do so?

Comment: `<% Fteam.all do |t| %>
    <option> <%= t.id %></option>
<% end %>' Returns nothing

Comment: Yes - TeamPlayer should have belongs_to :live_player.  You might want to test all this in the console.  `rails c` and try Fteam.all to see what's in the db.  And, what Rails version?

Comment: i used Fteam.all in the console and got return values. when i do Fteam.find_each it returns values in the html, but the Fteam.all in html returns nothing still

Comment: Try this instead `<%= select_tag :team_id, options_for_select(Fteam.all.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}) %>.

Comment: That did not work the following error happened: undefined method `name' for #<Fteam:0x47525b8>

Comment: You'd need to make sure it used attributes that are in your model - you may have a title or another way to identify teams by name.  You can use id for now.  I suspect you want something in the option other than a number for user to select?

Comment: do you mean fields from the table or the assocation of live_player?

Comment: I tried <%= select_tag :team_id, options_for_select(Fteam.all.map{|t| [t.team, t.id]}) %> Team is a field in the Fteams table, but that did not work